# Using ssh to echo text on remote server console

Tags: ssh, freebsd

```
ssh -n -l <login> <server> "echo hello"
```

Displays the output of the ssh command as "hello". Instead I would like to print the "hello" on the serial console of the remote (freebsd) server. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

see the manpage of `wall`.

alternatively, if you just want to write to (the first physical, not usb) serial port you could do `echo hello > /dev/ttyu0`, given you have set up COM1 as a terminal and also have the rights to write to that device. (e.g. you are root)